Generating function of the element-wise quotient of two sequences
Suppose I have two sequences which are represented by their generating functions,
$A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$ and $B(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n z^n$.
Suppose I know $A(z)$ and $B(z)$ exactly, but I do not necessarily have general formulae for the terms $a_n$ and $b_n$.
Suppose I define the function $C(z)$ by $$C(z) := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} z^n.$$
We may assume all the necessary nice things: $b_n\neq 0$ for all $n$, and $A(z)$, $B(z)$ and $C(z)$ are all well-defined within some radius of convergence. Are there any known results about how to obtain $C(z)$, or properties of it, given analytic expressions for $A(z)$ and $B(z)$, without having to compute their power series explicitly?

I wouldn't be surprised if the methods involved with the Hadamard product of two power series might be able to be adapted to this “Hadamard quotient”.

Writing $a_n/b_n=a_n\int _0^{\infty}e^{-sb_n}ds $ will lead to an Hadamard product.
